# Can't ssh in with public key

Tags: linux, ssh

I have two RH linux hosts, same build 'n everything, call them A & B.

I can ssh happily from A to B using a public key, but I simply cannot login to A from B (or from my desktop using putty & pageant for that matter) without being prompted for a password. It seems there must be something slightly different with A, but I can't fathom what.

The authorized_keys file and .ssh directory permissions are correct & PubkeyAuthentication is 'yes' in sshd_config.

Is there anything else that could be missing or anything that could have been changed from base build that would cause this to happen? I have checked and double checked the above and regenerated keys several times. I can also see it tries using the key when running ssh -v A, but fails.

Comment: It's not clear from your question if you have used different authorized_keys on A and B.  A needs to have the public key of B, and vice versa . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to debug this on the server if you can. If you have root access on the server, try becoming root and then run:

```
/path/to/sshd -ddd -p 1022
```

This will run an instance of the SSH server which will listen on port 1022, accept one connection, and  print debugging information to your terminal. Run your client as usual, except specify port 1022 as the port:

```
ssh -p 1022 user@A
```

The debugging information printed by the server will hopefully make it clear why you're being rejected.

Comment: I had to set a listen address (otherwise it defaulted to 0.0.0.0) and open the firewall for this to work, but it gave me the info I needed.  Annoyingly, it seems a monitoring agent changed ownership of the home directory for the user in question, but at least I know why it doesn't work!  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

> I can ssh happily from A to B using a public key, but I simply cannot
>   login to A from B...without being prompted for a password.

To get from X to Y, the public key of X has to be in the authorized_keys file of Y

Run the ssh command to get from A to B where it asks for a password e.g.

```
$ssh user@host
```

Then do Ctrl-C,  so you just know you have the ssh command right so it prompts for a password.

But this time, change `ssh` for `ssh-copy-id`

It will prompt for a password. Enter the password. Now Exit.

Then the next time you ssh in, it should go in automatically.

For that to work you have to have keys on A.

If you don't already have keys on A, then run  `$ssh-keygen`

Then do `ssh-copy-id` as described.

In connecting from A to B, All commands mentioned here so, ssh or ssh-copy-id or ssh-keygen, are run from A.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether iptables was configured to allow incoming ssh access

```
 iptables --list
```

It will list the existing iptable rules

You can allow incoming SSH only from a sepcific network with the following command

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -s 192.168.200.0/24 --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: As the OP describes it, he can connect to the server. He just can't authenticate with a key. Iptables wouldn't affect that.